# Can an electric stove infinite switch for a small burner be used to control a large burner?

Tags: electrical, stove

I have an electric stove model# JBS55DM2WW.  A small burner and large burner burnt out.  I replaced the larger burner to see if it was salvageable in the first place.  It worked but the infinite switch was bad and kept the stove on.  So I took the smaller burner's inifinite switch and replaced the large burner's infinite switch. I didn't realize the amps are different.  Is this ok to use like this?

I suspect since the amps being drawn by the switch is lower that the larger burner should be able to handle it and it will be ok.  Is this alright for long term?

The small burner infinite switch is rated for 5.4-7.0 amps
The larger burner infinite switch is rated for 7.2-9.0 amps
Both switches are 240 volts.

I'm not an electrical guy.  I'm getting confused by what is out there about putting a lower amp outlet for a wall socket.  For instance a 15a won't run a 20amp appliance.  But to me my situation is different since the switch can only provide up to 7.0 amps the burner only gets 7.0 amps and might run cooler but still be ok.  Or am I wrong and the larger burner is trying to draw way more amps than the switch can provide and is therefore a hazard?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Welcome to SE. Please edit your question title into a coherent sentence so it's more clear to passers-by what you're asking.

Comment: It is the latter, the switch cannot control how much current the burner draws, and doesn't even know.  Those numbers are **ratings** that **should not** be exceeded, but that depends on your good design and responsible use: there's no *deus ex machina* which forces you to stay within limits.  Put a table saw on a 10A extension cord, can't stop you. Put L-rated (75 mph) tires on your sport pickup truck, nothing prevents this.  There is such a thing as a constant-current power supply, but one large enough for a 2kw burner would go for more than $35.

Answer (score 2):

I spent some time researching these infinite switches because they are failing on our 25-year-old GE range but by a different mode than you have. Ours are losing the lower end. They don't heat at all on low but do work above a certain setting.

The infinite switches are different part numbers for the two different burners and it is not clear to me that it is "safe" to use an infinite switch for a small burner on a large one. The wires and the sensing element in the small infinite switch might not be sized to carry the larger current drawn by the large burner and might overheat or fail somehow.

The current through the switch is determined by the size of the burner. The infinite switch regulates the heat of the burner by square wave time modulation of the current on a time scale of maybe a second. So when the current is on it would be at a higher value (9 A?) on the large burner than on the smaller one. It is questionable in my mind that it is wise to use the infinite switch for the smaller burner on the larger one.

I suggest you get the specified one for the larger burner and get a new heating element for the smaller burner.

Comment: The parts site I visited has the switches for about $20 each! For our stove they are more than that and I need all four. I wonder what the difference is?

Answer (score 1):

I tried it. I put a small burner infinity switch on a large burner (on a Kenmore stove).  The large burner (while using the smaller rated infinity switch) heated and would eventually boil water but would not get red hot. So the infinity switch for the small burner worked in a big burner, but didn't pass enough current to get it red. So, the big burner just took longer to boil water. The infinity switch has a mini-heater strip inside it, which bends a little metal piece.  As the metal piece gets warm its bending an opens a circuit which stops voltage/current to the burner, the mini-heater in the switch cools, bends back and then reconnects the circuit putting voltage/current back to the burner over and over again. The rotary dial preloads the switch to keep it on for longer or shorter times.  I didn't try the other way around with the larger switch on the smaller burner.  Suspect the infinity switch designed for a large burner would open longer thus heating the small burner much higher than the dial setting indicates. I recommend using the right type switch designed for the burner.